# Azure Event Hub - Authenticate user before Sending the events

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am able to send the events to the EventHub using below Link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-framework-getstarted-send#send-events

Above article is using Eventhub connection string to send the event hub. If someone (unknown user) know my event hub connection string they can also send the events.

**So i want add some users like below in the portal and Users from below("Access control" in below screen shot) list only can send the events to my EventHub. Is there any way restrict like this?**

[image]

Comment: It is in preview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-role-based-access-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. There is [a preview feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-role-based-access-control) as mentioned in the comment, it uses azure ad RBAC role to authorize access to eventhub, but this is just another different way, if someone knows your connection string, he can also send the events.

My workaround is to use the [Azure Keyvault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-overview) to store the connection string as a secret. Then you can set the `Access policies` of the keyvault, add the user/service principal which you want. Then only the users/service principals with the permissions can retrieve the secret.

In the sample which you mentioned, it uses the plain text 
`static string connectionString = "namespace connection string"`, I suppose you may think it is not safe. After you store the connection string in the keyvault, you could use `keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync` to get the secret to avoid to expose the connection string.

```
AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
             KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
             var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("https://<YourKeyVaultName>.vault.azure.net/secrets/AppSecret")
                     .ConfigureAwait(false);
             Message = secret.Value;
```

For more details, you could refer to the links below.

- [Quickstart: Set and retrieve a secret from Azure Key Vault using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-portal)
- [Tutorial: Use Azure Key Vault with an Azure web app in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app)
- [C# Retrieve Key, Secret, Certificate from Azure KeyVault](https://appswin.co.th/2018/02/26/c-retrieve-key-secret-certificate-from-azure-keyvault/)

Comment: so copying the connection string from key vault and saving to key vault a manual step, right?